# Framework and library to develop a webpage with database

Tags: library, web-development, framework

I'm going to start a final career project that's going to be a webpage with a database to store all the client information.

The webpage must be simple:

1. Responsive webpage.
2. Communication with the database for saving user information.
3. Be secure (for example, payments via PayPal with reliability).

I don't know what framework/library should I use:

- Django, Ruby, …
- SQL, MongoDB, FireDB …

What do you recommend for developing a good-looking webpage?

I already know C, Java, Python and SQL. I like Python, but I don't know if Django is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 points you mention can be achieved in almost any language and many frameworks, as they are simple and common needs of almost all projects anyway today on the web. Thus you should either use what you already know or something you wish to learn along the road of this project, or something for which you have a community around you (local or remote).

You say at the end : "a good-looking webpage". If you are speaking only about the graphical display, this is mostly unrelated to the language you use, the framework, and the database. It is only a "small" problem of design, which goes technically around HTML and CSS, but needs a "designer" eye to make good looking pages.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The main doubt is that I don't know what framework is more friendly or more used. I already know SQL, should i go after mysql or the rest of databases have some advantage against SQL? There is any tool that you can design webpages (I mean drag and drop) and you just have to import these on your webpage, or you have to code it with css+html?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't always need a framework to accomplish simple tasks. You need a solid understanding of the language/platform to interpret how the framework works. I'd suggest you to look into some web development courses on Coursera/EdX.

Nevertheless, my personal recommendations.

**Java:** You may want to look at Spring Framework [plenty of tutorials]

**Python:** Django

**Responsive Framework**: Bootstrap

But if you're interested in seeing what other companies probably use, refer to https://stackshare.io/

Comment: If I choose Django, I can develop a complete and responsive webpage, or I'll need something more?